# Python and C file read/write simultaneously

Tags: python, c, multithreading

I have some C code, which I have extended in Python. The extended C code has a function which append some structure to a binary file:

```
void writefunction(const struct struct1* some,const u_char* struct2){
    f=fopen('save.bin',"ab");
    if(f==NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fwrite(some,sizeof(struct struct1),1,f);
    fwrite(struct2,sizeof(u_char),4,f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Now I have imported code in Python. I want to start two threads in Python: One will run this writefunction() and other will read the same file. The writefunction is working correctly in one thread but the Python function reading from the file is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Are you just trying to pass data from one thread to another, or is there a reason you are writing a file?

Comment: What's your Python code and what isn't working?

Comment: Python code is simply a a code for file reading. I want to run both C and python function in thread. This is because the c writefunction is writing something which can be done only by c.

Comment: Your C function should just return data to the caller. Threads have several ways to communicate without using files. If you really can't figure out a way to do that, pass your data by writing to a pipe. Trying to synchronize i/o via disk file is masochism.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

The problem here is, that the content of the 'save.bin' file depends on the C-compiler you're using - and maybe on some command line parameters you pass to the compiler.

How the structure `struct1` is internally held in memory is compiler dependent - at least when using bitfields; also a compiler might add padding (see example below). You write the internal memory structure to a file.

If you want to exchange data with programs written in different languages (and maybe running on different servers) you should convert them using some 'wire' (serialization) protocol.

Proposal: Maybe go for JSON or XML.

Example for padding a structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct struct1 {
   char a;
   long b;
};

int main() {
   printf("%d %d %d\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(long), sizeof(struct struct1));
   return 0;
}
```

One possible output is:

```
1 8 16
```

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Some kinds of C structs would be laid out in a compiler independent way, but as long as the struct doesn't use bitfields it should be fine.

Comment: IMHO bitfields are completely compiler dependent - but also the padding between different fields in implementation specific. Reformulate the answer and add a small C example.

Comment: When i indivisually run the writefunction of c, by extending it in python, it create the file and i am able to read the file save.bin using my python function. But i want to read it simultaneously when cfunction write. Is there any way to do this?